# How variable are US voter registration and voting rules among US states and how do those compare with international norms?

Tags: united-states, voting, voter-registration

How different are the rules for registration and voting in different states, (specifically the rules on early voting and the rules on access to polling places during voting), and how do those practices differ from the norms in other advanced democracies?

---

Background of this question:

After a wave of new rules being passed by (mostly) Republican state legislatures, and an attempt by Congress to pass the [For The People act](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/1/text), there is much debate over reforming the US election rules; specifically about how to register to vote, and how to vote.

Democrats believe the 2021 Republican rules are [voter suppression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republican_efforts_to_make_voting_laws_more_restrictive_following_the_2020_presidential_election); Republicans argue that many Democrat-leaning states already have tighter rules (*e.g.* this paywalled [Wall Street Journal op-ed](https://www.wsj.com/articles/bidens-election-reform-deception-11617229306?mod=searchresults_pos13&page=1) by [Karl Rove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Rove)).

As a non-American, the state of US election rules looks like an inconsistent mess. My [previous question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/63348/8658) on this topic was too opinionated, so I'm asking this question in an attempt to put the general state of US election rules in a factual context.

Comment: Please try to find a representative Republican op-ed that's not behind a paywall, or at least paraphrase or quote the relevant portion.  (Note that quoting the Republican argument would also oblige quoting the Democratic view as well.)

Comment: This is now extremely broad as the elections vary a lot from state to state and there is no one standard.

Comment: @JoeW The question is about how *variable* election rules are. How can the existence of lots of variation be an objection to the question being posed?

Comment: @agc The single sentence description already summarises the entire argument: there are many states run by democrats whose rules are as restrictive as, for example, the new rules in Georgia. That's what the sentence says. That is Rove's entire argument (except for the details, which is what the question is about).

Comment: this might be a good start to look at:  https://www.brennancenter.org/our-work/research-reports/voting-laws-roundup-january-2021  Googling *comparison usa state laws federal election* got me there.

Comment: @matt_black, Not all readers here assume that the opinions of Karl Rove must be infallible.   The Q. lacks specific instances, (and cites a paywall source), which leaves SE readers guessing as to the merit of these assertions.

Comment: @agc I, too, don't assume Rove is trustworthy. But his argument is based on an assumption that there is huge variation in rules across US states and, possibly, on an assumption that most readers have no idea how much variation there is. Like Trump's argument against postal voting that lacked plausibility if readers had known several states had used it almost exclusively with no obvious problems. Hence the need for the question.

Comment: In my experience, Ballotpedia is usually pretty neutral, and their [article on voting policies](https://ballotpedia.org/Voting_policies_in_the_United_States) looks pretty comprehensive to me (at least if you click through to the individual "election governance in state X" sub-articles). As for "looks like an inconsistent mess" - that's the case for *everything* that's done at the state level. You *always* end up with 50 different sets of rules, because that's what it means for something to be administered by the states in the first place.

Comment: I wonder  "why the voting rules/laws are not centralized, so all states take the unified /standard approach".

Comment: Once again, it is confusing to ask about "rules for registration and voting in different states, (specifically the rules on early voting and the rules on access to polling places during voting)" because early voting and poll access are not registration.  My previous comment to that effect was deleted despite the fact that it was a suggestion for improving the question.  If you're interested in registration rules, you should not specify early voting and poll access.

Comment: @CGCampbell There is a huge debate about whether US state rules about voting are fair, reasonable and nondiscriminatory. You can't even *start* that debate unless you know what the differences are. If you think it doesn't matter that rules are different, then how do you rule out the state-level (and perfectly legal) laws that prohibited black people from voting in the 1960s in some states? And are current rules achieving the same effect in more subtle ways?

Answer (score 5):

The answer to the first part of the question "**How** variable are US registration and voting rules" is fairly simple. **There is great variability between states.** I would not presume to quantify that variability.  My go-to resource is the National Conference of State Legislatures research series [here](https://www.ncsl.org/research/elections-and-campaigns/election-laws-and-procedures-overview.aspx). On the intro page they say:

> To assist lawmakers in reviewing elections policy decisions, NCSL provides 50-state research on many election law and procedural issues including:...

At the NCSL site, they will direct you to NCSL research links that will describe the differences between the 50 states in 47 different subject areas of electoral policy/laws.

As to the second part of your question, **How** do those compare with international norms?, the international "norms" tend to be guidelines. One such 'international' publication from NDI [here](https://www.ndi.org/sites/default/files/Applying-International-Standards-ENG.pdf) states:

> International standards for democratic elections are not
> prescriptive norms.  They do not mandate that a particular
> election system or explicit laws be applied. Instead  they are
> principles to guide the development and implementation of
> election  systems, laws, policies and procedures concerning
> democratic election processes.

A description of world wide voter registration practices can be found at [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voter_registration#:%7E:text=In%20the%20UK%20voter%20registration,any%20time%20of%20the%20year). The article describes voter registration in 24 countries. A quick survey of those countries identified appears that the vast majority have "automatic" voter registration (For example registration at birth) or compulsory registration of all citizens / residents. Contrasting that international snapshot versus the US where (according to Pew Research [Pew link](https://www.pewtrusts.org/%7E/media/legacy/uploadedfiles/pcs_assets/2012/PewUpgradingVoterRegistrationpdf.pdf)) approximately 25% of the US population that is otherwise eligible to vote are not registered, rendering those persons unable to vote.

Comment: I think you are interpreting "norms" incorrectly. There are no international *rules* about how elections should be held. But there are typical practices about how voters are registered, how voting in person and by post are conducted and so on. That is what should be compared to the state-level rules in the US. The current US debate about whether changes in state rules are voter suppression or not is usually conducted without any data on variation inside the US or any comparison with typical practice elsewhere. Hence this question.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would identify an acceptable source/citation for these international norms.  Otherwise comparison (with the US “mess”)  is nearly impossible.

Comment: This isn't that hard. Here is a good summary of the [Key features for the UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elections_in_the_United_Kingdom); [key features for Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elections_in_Australia); [key features for France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elections_in_France). The key issues of interest are for national elections: how registration is done, who is eligible to vote and what the rules are for postal voting, plus some other details. On those alone the US is an outlier.

Comment: No argument from me that the US appears to be an “outlier”. However the sources you offer are not **international** norms but rather descriptions of the **national** norms of specific nations.

Comment: AS I said in the first comment here, you are misinterpreting "norms". There are no *rules* that force nations to do things a certain way. But there are common *features* in the electoral rules of many, if not most, advanced democracies. That is what I meant by "norm".

Comment: Perhaps (offered without specific knowledge), the difference is that the US permits each of their constituent providences to establish their own practices and rules, which leads to 50+ sets of rules as contrasted with other nations that establish uniform rules for each of their constituent states, provinces, cantons etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122816/discussion-between-bobe-and-matt-black).

Comment: @matt_black the three "key features" articles you link to describe three very different approaches to voter registration, each of which differs from the US system.  If you believe that there is a common "norm" to be inferred from those three systems, you should state in the question what you think it is.

Comment: @phoog Most of the major democracies I know have different ways to achieve essentially universal voter registration. It is the fact that they are *universal* that is the key feature that is worth comparing to the US where the majority of states don't aim for universal registration and some actively make it hard to achieve.

Comment: @matt_black from the Wikipedia article you cited, the UK does not seem to have universal registration.

Comment: @phoog UK has *compulsory* voter registration.

Comment: @matt_black the phrase "can apply to the electoral registration officer ... to be listed in that area's electoral register" implies a lack of compulsion.

Comment: @phoog read the registration procedure section. Forms are sent to all households annually. And fines exist if you don’t fill them in. I live there: it is hard to dodge being registered.

Comment: @matt_black with a focus on voter registration worldwide this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voter_registration#:~:text=In%20the%20UK%20voter%20registration,any%20time%20of%20the%20year. may be useful. I won't swear to the accuracy of this wiki article, but it does provide the fuel for international comparison. The comentary re UK voter registration is that it is compulsory, but rarely enforced. Also interesting that it is the responsibility of the head of the household to provide voter registration (of members of the household?)